# convert a list of long to a list of int java 8

Tags: java, integer, java-stream

I have a method which takes a list of integer as parameter. 
I currently have a list of long and want to convert it to a list of integer so I wrote :

```
  List<Integer> student =
  studentLong.stream()
  .map(Integer::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I received an error:

```
method "valueOf" can not be resolved.
```

Is it actually possible to convert a list of long to a list of integer?

Comment: `studentLong.stream().mapToInt(Long::intValue).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Remember the map function always gets the long object from stream in your case, hence call intValue of Long, as commented by @alfasin above.

Comment: It works now. Do you want to write your solution below so I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: Thanks that's fine - it's a dup.

Comment: It's not a dupe, at least not of the question it was linked to.

Comment: @alfasin I'd go ahead and write your answer

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd yes sir!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use a `mapToInt` with `Long::intValue` in order to extract the `int` value:

```
List<Integer> student = studentLong.stream()
           .mapToInt(Long::intValue)
           .boxed()
           .collec‌t(Collectors.toList(‌​))
```

The reason you're getting `method "valueOf" can not be resolved.` is because there is no signature of [`Integer::valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) which accepts `Long` as an argument.

**EDIT**
Per Holger's comment below, we can also do:

```
List<Integer> student = studentLong.stream()
           .map(Long::intValue)
           .collec‌t(Collectors.toList(‌​))
```

Comment: Instead of `.mapToInt(Long::intValue) .boxed()` you can simply use `.map(Long::intValue)`.

Comment: Thanks @Holger I'll add it to the answer!

Comment: I'm trying to do it the other way around, Integer to Long. Without boxed()   it doesn't compile. `.stream().mapToLong(Integer::longValue).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @Holger : .map doesnt convert to primitive int?

Comment: @user2296988 `map` on a `Stream<…>` always returns a `Stream<…>`, never an `IntStream`. When you use `map(Long::intValue)` on a `Stream<Long>`, it will invoke `intValue` on the `Long` objects, followed by an implicit boxing conversion to `Integer`. When you want an `IntStream`, you need `mapToInt`, but in this specific case, an `IntStream` is not intended.